# LabView Control (.ctl) to VB.NET Structure

Tags: vb.net, asp.net, labview

I created a control in LabView.  My LabView code writes data of that type to a binary file.  I want to read this data into a VB Structure.

Can I do this programmatically, or do I need to manually create a corresponding structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a .NET programmer, so I can't give a proper answer, but I doubt the data types are compatible (for example, LabVIEW is big endian, whereas VB.NET is little endian, so you would need to reverse the byte order on multibyte values, although I believe later LV versions allow you to change this when flattening the data).

There's a section in the LabVIEW help which describes how LV stores data in memory and flattened (on disk, in your case) and I don't think you'll have any choice other than to write code which will read the binary data and convert it to the VB.NET format (although one option which might be relevant is writing an LV DLL which will read the data and then output it in a cluster which can be imported into VB.NET as a structure. Such a solution will require you to have the LV RTE on every PC where you want to run this).